# Can the repository pattern fetch of data be filtered before returning results to the controller?

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, blazor-webassembly

This project is C# VS-2022 Blazor WASM with REST-API repository pattern for the database API.

I keep getting a compile error whenever I use a Where() condition in repository-functions.

> Error CS1061  'DbSet' does not contain a definition for
> 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting
> a first argument of type 'DbSet' could be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

For example
in a repository function:

```
returnRecs = (await appDbContext.MOTrip).Where(r => (r.UID_CUSTOMER == uidModel));
```

The reason I am trying to filter in the repository is because the DB-table 'MoTrip' contains 10's-of-thousands of records. I am thinking that getting ALL records `(await appDbContext.MOTrip)` followed by various filtering conditions in the controller would be wasteful.

In the case presented in this question, filtering by CUSTOMER would be 1/100 the number of records fetched by the repository-function.

Your answers and comments are welcome.  Thanks John.

Comment: You are trying to await a `DbSet<T>`. You simply cannot. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also note, that even with the `.Where` nothing is actually happening, yet.

Comment: Use an IQueryable and you can apply the where clause to the actual query instead of filtering afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I do not know how to use an IQueryable.  I shall research, but if you can provide an example following my above code, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would rather filter in the database rather than in memory, which will avoid pulling all 10000 records from the database. You can do that by applying `.Where` to the `DbSet`:

```cs
returnRecs = await appDbContext.MOTrip.Where(r => r.UID_CUSTOMER == uidModel)
                                      .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I do not know how to "...filter in the database..." from the repository.  I know exactly the SQL to do it but I do not know how this can be implemented in the API-repository that only deals with "tables/models".  Advice??? Thanks.

Comment: @JohnD I've provided the code to "filter in the database". When you apply `.Where()` or `.Select()` statements to `DbSet` object, it gets translated to SQL and is executed in the database when you call `.ToListAsync()` or some other methods of DbSet

Comment: I apologize for not observing the ".ToListAsync()" in your first reply to this question.  I tested the small change AND it WORKED.  I will mark this as the answer and thank you for both of your responses.  You are VERY SMART...Thx.